# How to access nested object info for nested functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I'm writing an app in Angular and have something like this:

```
$scope.items = [
    {'name':'someName',
    'title': 'someTitle',
    'filter': function(item){
        Filters.setTableTitle(this.title); //cannot get title
        ...
        }
    },
    {'name':'someName',
    'title': 'someTitle',
    'filter': function(item){
        Filters.setTableTitle(this.title);
        ...
        }
    }
];
```

An array of objects. Part of each object is a function, and inside the function I would like to call a function that grabs the title of that object itself in order to pass it into a greater scope for the rest of the app.

However, I can't grab the title for each object.

How would I access the title in order to use it here?

Thanks.

*Update*

Here is my HTML that uses (something very similar to) the code above. I'm using the code to create buttons.

```
<p ng-repeat="link in items">
    <block class="button" href="{{link.URL}}" title="{{link.title}}">
        <a class="hrefLink" href="{{link.URL}}" ng-click="Filters.setFilter(link.filter, link.title)">
            {{link.name}}
        </a>
    </block>
</p>
```

The function held within the `filter` part of each object returns information that is then passed into `Filters.setFilter()` which updates the DOM.

**Filters.setFilter()**

```
service.setFilter = function(filter, title){
    service.searchTerm = '';
    $spMenu.hide(); //close nav if open
    service.selectedFilter = filter;
    service.setTableTitle(title); //this does the job
};
```

I've rearranged the ways these functions work, and now simply pass in the title to the different functions. This gets the job done for what I *want*, but still could never solve the initial question at hand--how would I access part of an object from inside the object?

Comment: This is probably not a good idea to begin with.  Can you not make a service or a factory instead?  Making it a service/factory would allow you to easily inject other services/factories which may be useful in the future.  For example a localStorageService...

Comment: How does your html code look like? Is it in an ng-repeat?

Comment: This is used to generate a handful of buttons via ng-repeat. The filter function is called when a button is clicked, which rather than loads a new view, changes the filter and rearranges a corresponding table. 
This information itself doesn't need to go beyond its controller, but I'm trying to get the title from here into a factory so it can be used elsewhere. (Trying to pass it into my Filters factory.)

Comment: I have updated the question with my HTML code.

Comment: What does the `Filters.setFilter` function contain?

Comment: See my edited answer. Would it help you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Angular wery well so there could definitely be a much better soultion.

If you call the function yourself, just write it like this:

```
$scope.items[x].filter(item);
```

If it's called somewhere else and `this` doesn't contain the right object, you can enumerate all objects and bind the function to it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; ++i) {
  var item = $scope.items[i];
  item.filter = item.filter.bind(item);
}
```

Edit:

You have two choices. First you can just bind the function in HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="link in items">
    <block class="button" href="{{link.URL}}" title="{{link.title}}">
        <a class="hrefLink" href="{{link.URL}}" ng-click="Filters.setFilter(link.filter.bind(link))">
            {{link.name}}
        </a>
    </block>
</p>
```

Or you can edit the function to do it for you:

```
<p ng-repeat="link in items">
    <block class="button" href="{{link.URL}}" title="{{link.title}}">
        <a class="hrefLink" href="{{link.URL}}" ng-click="Filters.setFilter(link)">
            {{link.name}}
        </a>
    </block>
</p>

service.setFilter = function(link){
    service.searchTerm = '';
    $spMenu.hide(); //close nav if open
    service.selectedFilter = link.filter.bind(link);
};
```